# MobX not setting observable properly in my class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to make my react app as dry as possible, for common things like consuming a rest api, I've created classes that act as stores with predefined actions to make it easy to modify it.

Behold, big code:

```
import {autorun, action, observable} from 'mobx'

export function getResourceMethods(name) {
  let lname = name.toLowerCase()
  let obj = {
    methods: {
      plural: (lname + 's'),
      add: ('add' + name),
      addPlural: ('add' + name + 's'),
      rename: ('rename' + name),
    },
    refMethods: {
      add: ('add' + name + 'ByRef'),
      addPlural: ('add' + name + 'sByRef'),
      rename: ('rename' + name + 'ByRef'),
      setRef: ('set' + name + 'Ref'),
    },
    fetchMethods: {
      pending: (lname + 'Pending'),
      fulfilled: (lname + 'Fulfilled'),
      rejected: (lname + 'Rejected'),
    }
  }
  return obj
}

class ResourceItem {
  @observable data;
  @observable fetched = false;
  @observable stats = 'pending';
  @observable error = null;

  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

class ResourceList {
  @observable items = [];
  @observable fetched = false;
  @observable status = 'pending';

  constructor(name) {
    this['add' + name + 's'] = action((items) => {
      items.forEach((item, iterator) => {
        this.items.push(item.id)
      })
    })
  }
}

class ResourceStore {
  constructor(name, resourceItem, middleware) {
    let {methods} = getResourceMethods(name)

    this.middleware = middleware || []

    let items = methods.plural.toLowerCase()
    this[items] = observable({}) // <--------------- THIS DOES NOT WORK!

    // Add resource item
    this[methods.add] = action((id, resource) => {
      let item = this[items][id], data;

      if (item && item.fetched) {
        data = item.data
      } else {
        data = resource || {}
      }

      this[items][id] = new resourceItem(data)
      this.runMiddleware(this[items][id])
    })

    // Add several resource items
    this[methods.addPlural] = action((resources) => {
      resources.forEach((resource, iterator) => {
        this[methods.add](resource.id, resource)
      })
    })

    // Rename resource item
    this[methods.rename] = action((oldId, newId) => {
      let item = this[items][oldId]
      this[items][newId] = item

      if (oldId !== newId) {
        delete this[items][oldId]
      }
    })
    // Constructor ends here
  }

  runMiddleware(item) {
    let result = item;
    this.middleware.map(fn => {
      result = fn(item)
    })

    return result
  }
}

class ReferencedResourceStore extends ResourceStore {
  @observable references = {}
  constructor(name, resource, middleware) {
    super(name, resource, middleware)

    let {methods, refMethods, fetchMethods} = getResourceMethods(name)

    let getReference = (reference) => {
      return this.references[reference] || reference
    }

    this[refMethods.setRef] = action((ref, id) => {
      this.references[ref] = id
    })

    this[refMethods.add] = action((ref, data) => {
      this[methods.add](getReference(ref), data)
      this[refMethods.setRef](ref, getReference(ref))
    })

    this[refMethods.rename] = action((ref, id) => {
      this[methods.rename](getReference(ref), id)
      this[refMethods.setRef](ref, id)
    })

    // *** Fetch *** //

    // Resource pending

    this[fetchMethods.pending] = action((ref) => {
      this[refMethods.add](ref)
    })

    // Resource fulfilled

    this[fetchMethods.fulfilled] = action((ref, data) => {
      this[refMethods.add](ref, data)
      this[refMethods.rename](ref, data.id)

      let item = this[methods.plural][data.id];
      item.fetched = true
      item.status = 'fulfilled'
    })

  }
}

export {ResourceItem, ResourceList, ResourceStore, ReferencedResourceStore}
```

Now I'm just creating a simple user store:

```
class UserResource extends ResourceItem {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data)
  }

  @observable posts = new ResourceList('Posts')
  @observable comments = new ResourceList('Comment')
}

// Create store
class UserStore extends ReferencedResourceStore {}
let store = new UserStore('User', UserResource)
```

And `mobx-react` connects just fine to the store, can read it as well. BUT, whenever I do any changes to the items (`users` in this case, the name of the property is dynamic) property, there are no reactions. I also noticed that in chrome, the object property does not have a "invoke property getter" in the tree view:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't read the entire gist, but if you want to declare a new observable property on an existing object, use `extendObservable`, `observable` creates just a boxed observable, so you have an observable *value* now, but not yet an observable *property*. In other words:

```
this[items] = observable({}) // <--------------- THIS DOES NOT WORK!
```

should be:

```
extendObservable(this, {
  [items] : {}
})
```

N.b. if you can't use the above ES6 syntax, it desugars to:

```
const newProps = {}
newProps[items] = {}
extendObservable(this, newProps)
```

to grok this: https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/react.html

**Edit**: oops misread, you already did that, it is not hacky but the correct solution, just make sure the extend is done before the property is ever used :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was hacky to create a fresh version of the object and setting it as itself to trigger the reaction.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hacky solution:

First off, use `extendObservable` instead (this is the correct solution) and then use a fresh version of the object and set it as the property.

```
let items = methods.plural.toLowerCase()
    extendObservable(this, {
      [items]: {}
    })

    // Add resource item
    this[methods.add] = action((id, resource) => {
      let item = this[items][id], data;

      if (item && item.fetched) {
        data = item.data
      } else {
        data = resource || {}
      }

      this[items][id] = new resourceItem(data)
      this.runMiddleware(this[items][id])

      this[items] = {...this[items]}
    })
```

This works, not sure if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are using `extendObservable` or using an [observable map](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/map.html).
For reference see the documentation of [observable](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/observable.html) and specifically:

> To create dynamically keyed objects use the asMap modifier! Only initially existing properties on an object will be made observable, although new ones can be added using extendObservable.